# Angular Material md-input-container takes large space

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html, angular-material

I am working with a angular material sample. According to my default code `md-input-container` takes large space. My output as follows.

[image]

But I have found `md-input-content` with less space as follows.

[image]

I am not sure how to do that. My example  of `md-input-container` code as follows.

```
  <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-sm>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input md-maxlength="50" required name="name" ng-model="user.name"/>
  </md-input-container>
```

Comment: You want more than one `md-input-container` in one row. right ?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: No I couldn't go through it

Answer (score 6):

you can read [this](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/introduction)  documentation for that

simple code snippet about your question:

```
<div flex="100" class="flex flex-col">
    <md-input-container class="md-block">
       <label>Name</label>
       <input md-maxlength="50" required name="name" ng-model="user.name"/>
    </md-input-container>

    <md-input-container class="md-block">
           <label>Surname</label>
           <input md-maxlength="50" required name="surname" ng-model="user.surname"/>
    </md-input-container>
</div>
```